# Javascript: Equality Comparison between two Object/ Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let us guess two objects with same property:

```
var x = {a : 'some'},
      y = {a: 'some'};
```

output:

`x == y;` and `x === y;` both give false

Similarly for two array,

```
var p = [1, 2, 3],
      q = [1,2,3];
```

`p == q` and `p === q` both give `false`.

But for if I do following:

```
var x = y = {a: 'some'};
var p = q = [1, 2, 3];
```

All above comparison give `true`.

Why Javascript do such thing? Explain Please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> All above comparison give `true`.

Right. You've specifically set `p` and `q` so they refer to the same object.

With object references, both `==` (if both sides are object references) and `===` will check to see if the references are pointing to the *same object*. If you have two identical, but separate, objects, both will always be `false`.

So for example:

```
var a = {}; // a points to an object
var b = {}; // b points to a _different_ object
console.log(a === b); // "false"
console.log(a == b);  // "false"

var c = {}; // c points to an object
var d = c;  // d points to _the same_ object
console.log(c === d); // "true"
console.log(c == d);  // "true"
```

The *content* of the objects is irrelevant, it's the identity of them that's being checked.

Note that this is not true if you use `==` and only one side is an object reference (e.g., the other side is a number, a primitive string, `undefined`, etc.). In that case, the object reference will be asked to convert itself (to either a string or a number, depending on what the other thing is), and then the converted result will be used for the comparison. This can lead to surprising behavior (for instance, `"2" == [[[[[2]]]]]` is `true` because the array is asked to turn itself into a string, which it does via `join` [which will ask its element to convert itself to a string, and so on], and you end up with `"2"` on the right-hand side). So I typically prefer `===` ("strict equality" over `==` ("loose equality").

Comment: Yea, var x = {a : 'some'}, y = {a: 'some'}; are pointing to TWO different - in memory but similar - objects.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because

```
var p = [1, 2, 3],
q = [1,2,3];
```

creates two instances of arrays. Equality operators in JS, when comparing non-primitive data, only check if they are the same instance, don't do deep check of values or properties.

With code

```
var p = q = [1, 2, 3];
```

you are creating ONE instance of the array and assign this instance to variables `p` and `q`. So, both variables store reference to the same instance, so equality operator will return true.

Comment: +1. More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Answer (score 2):

In this cases, the variables point to two separate objects, thus not equal.

```
var x = {a:'some'}, // one object with "a" = "some"
    y = {a:'some'}; // another object with "a" = "some"

var p = [1,2,3],    // one array with 1,2 and 3
    q = [1,2,3];    // another array with 1,2 and 3
```

But in this case, they point to the same object, thus equal

```
var x = y = {a: 'some'};
//is like:
var x = {a:'some'}, // x points to an object
    y = x;          // y is given reference to whatever x is pointing at


var p = q = [1,2,3];
//is like:
var p = [1,2,3],    // p points to an array
    q = p;          // q is given reference to whatever p is pointing at
```